# OAuth issue in API gateway

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, cors

I am facing the OAuth issue, details are below:
I am having two microservices:
registration-service(https://github.com/choudharylakshyaveer/registration-service)
student-service(https://github.com/choudharylakshyaveer/student-service)

For these two I have added :
cloud-config-server(https://github.com/choudharylakshyaveer/cloud-config-server)
naminig-server(https://github.com/choudharylakshyaveer/naming-server)
gateway(https://github.com/choudharylakshyaveer/api-gateway)

FrontEnd: is at react js: https://github.com/choudharylakshyaveer/chargie

For first time use, a new user need to be register that can be done from curl:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8765/user/save' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "user@chargie.com",
    "password": "chaudhary22",
    "enabled": true,
    "roles": [
        "ROLE_ADMIN",
        "ROLE_USER"
    ]
}'
```

To login using the above registered user, below can be run from cUrl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8765/login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "user@chargie.com",
    "password": "chaudhary22"
}'
```

Once I log In and get the Bearer token, after that I am facing cors issue from the reactJs FE, bu same request is working fine from the Postman, below is request from postman:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8765/REGISTRATION-SERVICE/test' \
--header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' \
--header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type' \
--header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS' \
--header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' \
--header 'Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJyb2xlIjpbIlJPTEVfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwic3ViIjoibHZzIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU4OTM0NzIxLCJleHAiOjE2NTg5NjM1MjF9.MN6lCrwLB2bBDBLp-HG4nlSRlyhoR2cQDSRGvJCD2WwDMojhei0wW7xVuDwVCtRUANK02aQMhqagafB2csDWWg'
```

## Below is the code used to hit request from ReactJs FE:

```
var config = {
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:8765/REGISTRATION-SERVICE/test',
            headers: { 
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
              'Access-Control-Max-Age': '1800',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'content-type',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS'
            },
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          };
          
          axios(config)
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

And this request gives me CORS issue:
[image]

Snippet of the ServerSecurityContextRepository's overridden method used in SecurityContextRepository class of api-gateway:

```
@Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange swe) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = swe.getRequest();
        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        String authHeader = headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String authToken = authHeader.substring(7);
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
            return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).map((authentication) -> {
                return new SecurityContextImpl(authentication);
            });
        } else {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }
```

Here when the request is coming from the Postman then below is receievd in the **`headers`** variable:

```
[access-control-allow-credentials:"true", access-control-allow-headers:"content-type", access-control-allow-methods:"PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS", access-control-allow-origin:"*", access-control-max-age:"1800", authorization:"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJyb2xlIjpbIlJPTEVfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwic3ViIjoibHZzIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU4OTM0NzIxLCJleHAiOjE2NTg5NjM1MjF9.MN6lCrwLB2bBDBLp-HG4nlSRlyhoR2cQDSRGvJCD2WwDMojhei0wW7xVuDwVCtRUANK02aQMhqagafB2csDWWg", user-agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.29.0", accept:"*/*", postman-token:"6c0d7a9a-dcde-45d7-8422-1476682db9f4", host:"localhost:8765", accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, br", connection:"keep-alive"]
```

But when same request comes from Front end then below is receievd in the **`headers`** variable and it seems to be malformed:

```
[host:"localhost:8765", connection:"keep-alive", pragma:"no-cache", cache-control:"no-cache", accept:"*/*", access-control-request-method:"GET", access-control-request-headers:"access-control-allow-credentials,access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,access-control-max-age,authorization", origin:"http://localhost:3000", user-agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", sec-fetch-mode:"cors", sec-fetch-site:"same-site", sec-fetch-dest:"empty", referer:"http://localhost:3000/", accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, br", accept-language:"en-US,en;q=0.9"]
```

So, Here I am not receiving proper Authorization header on backend's **headers** variable so that I can take Bearer token to validate it.

Comment: This does not appear to be enough information to answer  your question. How does someone log in? What does the HTTP request/response look like? You state you do not receive the proper Authorization header in the "OAuth issue". What does the HTTP request/response look like? What do you mean by "proper"? Does the header exist, but is malformed, is it missing all together, etc? In your original request for help you mentioned that it was a CORS issue https://twitter.com/lakshyaveercha2/status/1551549832300376064 Can you explain why that is?

Comment: @RobWinch I have updated the details, please mention if anything required more to update

Comment: CORS headers have to be set on the *Response* at the *backend*, not in the request at the frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working after adding cors, complete code below for  SecurityWebFilterChain's method :

```
http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) -> {
                return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                    swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                });
            }).accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> {
                return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                    swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                });
            }).and()
            .cors().configurationSource(request -> {
                CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","PUT","PATCH", "DELETE","OPTIONS"));
                config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                return config;
            })
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .and()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/user/save").permitAll() //line added
            .anyExchange()
            .authenticated()
            
            .and().build();
```